# How to update record in database from web application?

Tags: servlets, jdbc

I am trying to do a assignment. I want to insert data into `MySql from a .jsp page`. Data are

```
ID, First Name and Last Name.
```

What i understand is I need to create a Input.jsp page where i can input ID, First Name and Last Name and take these values to servlet page and update my table in MYsql.

Does any one know where i can find this example? I am using Jdbc, tomcat and mysql.

Comment: You should do your assignment by yourself. And if you stuck, raise your question here.

Answer (score 0):

First off, be advised that accessing your database directly from JSP is not a good practice.  For ease of maintenance you're better off implementing your business logic and database access code in Java.  Your JSP's should contain code to display the UI and nothing more.  Hopefully your future assignments will have you do this.

Here are two tutorials that will help you with accessing MySQL via JDBC from JSP: [JSP - Database Access](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm) and [Connecting to MySQL database and retrieving and displaying data in JSP page](http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysqldatabase.shtml).